# What is Charles Renouvier's Conception of God?

Tags: theology, idealism

Charles Renouvier (1815-1903) was a French philosopher. He adopted a view of the finiteness of space and time.

He also adopted a view of finiteness of God.

Could you, please, give me the whole picture adopted by Renouvier about God?

Was he a pantheist or a panentheist?

What about Immenance and Transcendentalism of God?

Was he Idealist?

Did he consider humankind the ultimate manifestation of God?

Comment: Renouvier's work merits attention but your Question, as developed in the text box, is really many questions. Could you rephrase it so that it has a single focus?

Comment: @geoffreythomas thank you for your editing. As I mentioned in the question, I want the whole picture of Renouvier's view about God. The subquestions help in the answer. Thank you.